# html form button carrying array element as string

Tags: php, html, forms, button, session-variables

I want to be able to carry `$_POST['v']` (string) to delete.php using an HTML form button.

```
$directory = "exports/";
$contents = scandir($directory,1);
foreach($contents as $k => $v) {
if ($v != '.' && $v != '..') { 
  echo "<a href=\"$directory" . $v . "\">".$v."</a>";
  echo "<form action=\"delete.php\" method=\"post\"><a class=\"buttonnohover\"><input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" name=\"v\" value=\"Delete\" /></form>  <br>";
  }
}
```

At the moment the submit button simply brings back string(6) "Delete". I want $_POST['v'] to equal each individual $v (filename within the directory) carried on each button.

What am I not doing right?

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I think you want the submit button to have a value, is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to get the value of `$v` to delete.php using the form, you can use a hidden input:

```
echo '<a href="'.$directory.$v.'">'.$v.'</a>';
echo '<form action="delete.php method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="v" value="'.$v.'" />
    <a class="buttonnohover"><input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Delete" />
    </form><br>';
```

Currently you are getting "Delete" back, because it is the value of the button - just as you defined it in the HTML.

Additionally I would suggest renaming `$v` to `$filename` - currently it is only a cryptic variable, because the context is small of course you know what it holds, but only by looking at other lines of code. When you name it `$filename`, you'll directly know what the content of that variable will be.